# c#, How can i print in Datagridview each row center?

Tags: c#

I want print string by Datagridview.

I use this code.

```
DataGirdview.Rows.Insert('rownumber', 'string');
```

So, how can i print string in datagridview each row center?

Comment: You want to have your string printed in the center of the DataGridView? Your last question confuses a lot.

Comment: Is there there anyway you could reformulate your question? As it is written now, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: what do u mean by **datagridview each row center?**

Comment: I think he wants text align center in cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [DataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.alignment(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating the position of the cell content
>   within a DataGridView cell.

Also check [DataGridViewContentAlignment Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx)